# Ionic: Check Internet Connection using Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on Ionic Framework, and facing issues using the [Apache Cordova Network API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md) to detect internet connection in Android App.
I have referred [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/) tutorial and also created a demo project, which works fine.

I have followed the below steps. [from the tutorial]

1. `ionic start testApp sidemenu`
2. `ionic platform add android`
3. Open `testApp/www/js/app.js`
4. Copy paste this code

   ```
   if(window.Connection) {

     if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
         alert('There is no internet connection available');
     }else{
         alert(navigator.connection.type);
     }
   }else{
         alert('Cannot find Window.Connection');
   }
   ```
5. Install Cordova Plugin `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`
6. Build `ionic build android`
7. Run `ionic run android`

This works fine

**Issue**

8. Copy Paste `www` from `mainproject` to `testApp` and do steps 6 and 7

I get a alert `Cannot find Window.Connection`

**After** copy pasting the `app.js` looks like this

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    // check internet connection
    //alert(window.Connection);
    alert('Hi')
    try {
       alert('Naviagtor says'+navigator.connection.type);
     }
    catch(err) {
       alert( 'Error '+ err.message) 
       //here i get 'Error cannot read property type of undefined'
     }

if(window.Connection) {
    if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        alert('There is no internet connection available');
    }else{
        alert(navigator.connection.type);
    }
}else{
    alert('Cannot find Window.Connection');
}

  });
})
```

The moment I copy paste my `app.js` and `controllers.js` to the `testApp/www/js` directory the whole thing blows up.

Any help in debugging is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**Note**

I do have `cordova.js` in `index.html`.

I have re installed `platforms` and `plugins` after copy paste as well.

Comment: did you try printing navigator.connection.type before checking for window.Connection? What does it say?

Comment: thanks for replying, I have updated the code above. As you said, I tried printing the `navigator.connection.type` but it looks like the object is undefined.

Comment: run cordova plugins ls.. is sms plugin listed. If not remove the platforms android/ios and re add them

Comment: please make sure www from mainproject contains plugins folder and also the plugin which you installed.

Comment: the www folder does not contain the plugins folder. It's outside the www folder in the `mainproject`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved a similar issue by using [ngcordova](http://ngcordova.com/) . It gives you an angular wrapper around the plugin that implements promises.

Often Cordova plugins aren't ready when you try to call them, using the promise interface you can avoid getting undefined errors.

I stole the example from the ngcordova page on the network plugin [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/).

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()

    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()

    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()


    // listen for Online event
    $rootScope.$on('networkOffline', function(event, networkState){
      var onlineState = networkState;
    })

    // listen for Offline event
    $rootScope.$on('networkOffline', function(event, networkState){
      var offlineState = networkState;
    })

  }, false);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, the `$cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()` returns `0` instead of `Connection.NONE` and `$cordova.isOnline()` returns an error. I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: Did you follow install instructions carefully and are you running it on a device or AVD? 

I personally used a test call to my server to see if I have a connection. Since having wifi doesn't mean internet access. Maybe write a call to the server and handle returns to see if you have a connection.

Comment: Use **$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline'** and **$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online'** instead your listeners

Answer (score 6):

For anyone new visiting and having problems with getting Armed10's answer working, you may want to check the post I wrote which goes literally step by step telling you where and why you should put some piece of code (may be useful if you're just starting with Ionic): http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/codeproject/check-network-information-change-with-ionic-famework/.

Also, I made the example code available freely on Github: https://github.com/Hitman666/IonicNetworkInfo.

**edit:** As per StackOverflow's rules, I'm adding the post content here as well:

Step by step on how to make this yourself

Start a new Ionic project by doing:

```
ionic start IonicNetworkInfo blank
```

Then, change the directory to the newly created IonicNetworkInfo:

```
cd IonicNetworkInfo
```

Install ngCordova with Bower:

```
bower install ngCordova
```

If by some chance you don’t have bower installed, you can install it with npm:

```
npm install bower -g
```

Open up the www/index.html file in your favorite editor, and add the reference to ngCordova (just above the cordova.js script):

```
<!-- This is what you should add, the cordova below you'll already have -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Install the ngCordova network plugin by executing the following command in your Terminal/Command prompt (you should do this from the root directory of your app; so, in our case the IonicNetworkInfo directory):

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

To check if you have successfully installed the plugin, you can run the following command (from the root directory – I won’t be repeating this anymore; when I say you should run some command from the Terminal/Command prompt that, in this case, means from the root directory of the application):

```
cordova plugin list
```

You should see the following output:

```
> cordova plugin list                                                                                                                           
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
```

Open up the www/js/app.js file and add ngCordova to the dependencies list, so that basically the first line looks like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Create a new controller in the www/js/app.js file called MyCtrl, with the following content:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        $scope.$apply();

        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            $scope.isOnline = true;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("got offline");
            $scope.isOnline = false;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

  }, false);
})
```

In this controller you attach an event listener on the deviceready event (because it could be that the device would not have been yet initialized when this code runs) and you get the network information with:

```
$cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
```

The information, about weather you’re connected to the internet is obtained with the following line:

```
$scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
```

Then, you register two events $cordovaNetwork:online and $cordovaNetwork:online which trigger when the device gets online/offline. In them you then just update the $scope variables ().
Just for reference, the whole content of the www/js/app.js file should be:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        $scope.$apply();

        // listen for Online event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            $scope.isOnline = true;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

        // listen for Offline event
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("got offline");
            $scope.isOnline = false;
            $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

            $scope.$apply();
        })

  }, false);
});
```

In the index.html file, inside the ion-content tag paste the following content:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <h1>Network: {{network}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <ion-toggle ng-model="isOnline" ng-checked="item.checked">
            <h1 ng-show="isOnline">I'm online</h1>
            <h1 ng-show="! isOnline">I'm offline</h1>
        </ion-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what we do here is we show the contents of the network variable (which is attached to the $scope via the controller). Also, by using the ion-toggle component we show the “I’m online” / “I’m offline” notifications.

Just for reference, the content of the whole index.html file should look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content padding="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <h1>Network: {{network}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <ion-toggle ng-model="isOnline" ng-checked="item.checked">
                        <h1 ng-show="isOnline">I'm online</h1>
                        <h1 ng-show="! isOnline">I'm offline</h1>
                    </ion-toggle>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to test this application you should run it on your device (because you can’t disable network in iOS simulator). If you have an Android device plugged to your computer (and all the SDKs in place) you can run the following to commands to get your application running on your Android device:

```
ionic build android && ionic run android
```

Comment: @kleopatra: thanks for the reminder. However, is it "allowed" to basically post the full contents of my post here as well? I mean, I have no problem with it, I'm just asking - if so, thanks, and I'll update it shortly.

Comment: Hi @Nikola, I am experiencing the same issue but the structure of my code is a bit different. Just wanted to ask how you can implement this as a service/factory. I've included some more detail about my particular issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123495/checking-network-status-on-ionic-application. I'm short, I want to create a real-time connection status monitor for my application but apart from setinerval (as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40201808), I really have no idea. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

just use this code in your app.js inside .run

```
if (window.Connection) {
       if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
         toast.show("Internet is disconnected on your device");
       };
     };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you updated recently (**running cordova 5.0**), my guess would be the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` needs to be installed. After installing, add this to **config.xml** to allow all http/s requests :

```
allow-intent href="http://\*/\*"

allow-intent href="https://\*/\*"
```

Shell:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you call the "connection", you need to check the device:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: How would you implement this in a factory/service?