# TypeError: ConnectionService.isOnline is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep the following error message when trying to instantiate my service in the controller:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: ConnectionService.isOnline is not a function
    at new MonitorService (http://localhost:8100/app/services/connection.service.js:33:24)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18010:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17850:24)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17995:19)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17834:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17995:19)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17794:37
    at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17941:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17965:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18007:18) <ion-nav-view name="tab-search" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="android">
```

This is my code so far:

**search.controller.js**

```
/*
 *
 */
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dingocv.controllers')
    .controller('SearchController', SearchController)


    function SearchController($scope, $interval, CategoryService, MonitorService) {
        $scope.connected = $interval(MonitorService, 1000);

        CategoryService.getCategoryList().then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.categories = dataResponse.data;
        });
    }

})();
```

**connection.service.js**

```
/*
*
*/
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dingocv.services')
    .service('ConnectionService', ConnectionService)
    .service('MonitorService', MonitorService)


    function ConnectionService($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {
        return {
            isOnline: function() {
                if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
                    return $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
                } else {
                    return navigator.OnLine;
                }
            },
            isOffline: function() {
          if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
            return !$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
          } else {
            return !navigator.OnLine;
          }
            }
        }
    }

    function MonitorService() {
        if(ConnectionService.isOnline()) {
            return true;
        } else if(ConnectionService.isOffline()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

})();
```

**search.view.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
    <ion-content>
        <div ng-show="!connected">You are not connected</div>
        <div ng-show="connected">You are connected</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the dependency injection in `connection.service.js`

**connection.service.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dingocv.services')
    .service('ConnectionService', ConnectionService)
    .service('MonitorService', MonitorService)


    function ConnectionService($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {
        return {
            isOnline: function() {
                if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
                    return $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
                } else {
                    return navigator.OnLine;
                }
            },
            isOffline: function() {
          if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
            return !$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
          } else {
            return !navigator.OnLine;
          }
            }
        }
    }
    // injecting ConnectionService in this service
    function MonitorService(ConnectionService) {
        if(ConnectionService.isOnline()) {
            this.status = true;
        } else if(ConnectionService.isOffline()) {
            this.status = false;
        }
    }

})();
```

**search.controller.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dingocv.controllers')
    .controller('SearchController', SearchController)


    function SearchController($scope, $interval, CategoryService, MonitorService) {
        $interval(function(){
            $scope.connected = MonitorService.status
        }, 1000);

        CategoryService.getCategoryList().then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.categories = dataResponse.data;
        });
    }

})();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi I tried the above and now get the following error message: `TypeError: fn is not a function
    at callback (ionic.bundle.js:25611)
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30211)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30503)
    at tick (ionic.bundle.js:25601)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:26794(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:23507$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:30213$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30503tick @ ionic.bundle.js:25601`

Comment: Try this in **search.controller.js**. `$interval(function(){$scope.connected = MonitorService();}, 1000);`

Comment: I've added the code and now I get this error `ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: MonitorService is not a function
    at search.controller.js:14
    at callback (ionic.bundle.js:25611)
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30211)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30503)
    at tick (ionic.bundle.js:25601)`

Comment: I've made two changes in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40201808/revisions , refined the connection service to proper syntax and refactored the controller , hope this helps.