# Handle offline state when starting an ionic app on ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

Im developing and app on ionic 1 and triying to case where the app is started in a offline state, I've already seen http://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/, [Ionic: Check Internet Connection using Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916953/ionic-check-internet-connection-using-cordova) and actually endup with this code:

```
console.log("checking network", $cordovaNetwork);

      if(!navigator.onLine){
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: "Internet disconnected!",
          content: "Please check your connection before moving on"
        })
        .then(function(result){
          if(!result){
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
          }
        });
      }
```

And this partially works, the thing is that when I start the app from zero (kill it and reopen), I start getting errors due not being able to load js files (Failed to load resource: The internet connection...), and the app never gets to the check connection line and only sits on a horrible white screen.

From the logs I can see that the only actual angular error is related to firebase (Module firebase is not available) and I believe this is avoiding the app to get to my check connection code, but I don't know if downloading and keeping a local reference of firebase js is the right solution and have the code move forward the firebase error.

Comment: I'm not using firebase and have the same problem. The app sits on a white screen. Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Hi, I just added an answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually the issue was split into 2 parts, first, first keep in mind that while working on dev mode, when you run your ionic app, it needs to connect to the your dev machine, or it won't run any code, so if you try to test the offline check while running like this, you are always going to end up with a white screen, basically the app loads the resources from your dev machine.

now for the actual requirement of showing an error to the user if there's no network connectivity, this code does the work for me

```
console.log("checking network", $cordovaNetwork);

  if(!navigator.onLine){
    $ionicPopup.confirm({
      title: "Internet disconnected!",
      content: "Please check your connection before moving on"
    })
    .then(function(result){
      if(!result){
        ionic.Platform.exitApp();
      }
    });
  }
```

for testing, as @gerdi suggested "You can test offline status (in dev mode ) by running to a device with ionic run android"

Comment: So it isnt possible to run without internet connection?

Comment: You can test offline status (in dev mode ) by running to a device with `ionic run android`

Comment: You are rigth and I added it to the answer